# Reuse style in android theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I have something like this in my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Default" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Which works, but I have much more than the 3 colors, and I'd like to avoid code duplication. I'm trying to use dot notation inheritance to do so. Here's what I tried:

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Default" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

But it doesn't work: the colors defined in AppTheme are not inherited by AppTheme.Default and AppTheme.NoActionBar. Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/32648464/9365212 and this one also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38083837/9365212

Comment: Thanks. Seems there's no solution, "parent=" inheritance wins over dot inheritance. The first link suggesting to recopy the NoActionBar theme looks future unproof to me. Looks like I'll have to copy paste 3 times all my themes ><

Comment: You can check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Customize): *If you use the dot notation to extend a style, and you also include the parent attribute, then the parent styles override any styles inheritted through the dot notation.* You could define a default theme and then for `.NoActionBar` (easy, just 2 attrs)  and `.DarkActionBar` (not so easy) don't use the parent and just copy their attrs in the style. But it's not worth it.

Comment: Yes I ended up copy-pasting my values. Thanks!